# matlab - pushbutton seems to be already clicked

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I designed GUI with 5 pushbuttons and they all work fine but 2 of them appear like they are clicked on constantly [blueish] and this wont change even when clicked on.
Nevertheless they work fine .
I want to know how can I change those button to be normal like the 3 others.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? You can post a link and I or someone else will upload the picture on the website. Thanks.

Comment: [link]http://srv1.jpg.co.il/10/5509d04d4ed5a.jpg
mix time button and new time mix button